# Adding OptionButtons to the Userform programatically in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, label

I am very new to VBA programming. 
My scenario is I will get a list of String values I need these values to be displayed to the user using radio buttons on a small window so that whenever the user selects any value by clicking on the radio button I should be able to get that value in the VBA code. I searched for adding options button in the user form in the internet I got some solution which use GUI method of creating option buttons. But I need it done through program. I found a helpful thread in stackoverflow ([How can I dynamically add a radio button on a form using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049347/how-can-i-dynamically-add-a-radio-button-on-a-form-using-vba) ) I used this but still I am unable to get any label or button on the user form, a plain userform will be displayed. So anybody please give information regarding this.

The code is :

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    lResult As Variant    ' this is a array which contains string vaues to be dispayed as radio button.

    ' Some operatin is done here to get the list of values in lResult

    Dim rad As Variant
    Set rad = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "radioFoo", True)
    rad.Caption = "bar"
    rad.Left = 10
    rad.Width = 10
    rad.Top = 10
End Sub
```

UserForm1 is the userform which I created using Insert option in VBA menu bar.
I tried to add a single button on the userform. I did not use initialize function on userform. There is button on excel sheet Button1 I am calling this function on clicking that button.

Thank you

Comment: Why not instead use a listbox with "list style" set to "listStyleOption" and format it to look like a set of option buttons (no border, back color same as form..) ? That's going to be much easier to manage.

Comment: What code do you currently have in your `UserForm_Initialize()`? It is very hard to answer a vague question like this without seeing the code you already have.

Comment: @Declan_k Thank you very much. I am sorry I added the code part that I am using. Please let me know what correction I should make.

Comment: @Tim Williams : Thank you for your response. I'll try to follow your method. If possible could you please give me any example link or information link on your method.

Comment: I don't think it really needs much explanation - really a pretty simple thing to do: drop a listbox on your form, set its properties to give it the appearance you want, and populate it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a form named `UserForm1` that contains a button named `CommandButton1`

[image: UserForm]

You can set the Initialize method for your UserForm to programmatically create a group of radio buttons

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim OptionList(1 To 3) As String
    Dim btn As CommandButton
    Set btn = UserForm1.CommandButton1
    Dim opt As Control
    Dim s As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    OptionList(1) = "Option 1"
    OptionList(2) = "Option 2"
    OptionList(3) = "Option 3"

    For Each s In OptionList
        Set opt = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "radioBtn" & i, True)
        opt.Caption = s
        opt.Top = opt.Height * i
        opt.GroupName = "Options"

        UserForm1.Width = opt.Width
        UserForm1.Height = opt.Height * (i + 2)

        i = i + 1
    Next

    btn.Caption = "Submit"
    btn.Top = UserForm1.Height - btn.Height + (0.5 * opt.Height)
    btn.Left = (UserForm1.Width * 0.5) - (btn.Width * 0.5)

    UserForm1.Height = UserForm1.Height + btn.Height + (0.5 * opt.Height)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UserForm1.Controls.Count - 1
        If UserForm1.Controls(i) Then
            SelectedOption = UserForm1.Controls(i).Caption
        End If
    Next

    UserForm1.Hide
End Sub
```

If you want to pull your list from a sheet you can change

```
Dim OptionList(1 To 3) As String

OptionList(1) = "Option 1"
OptionList(2) = "Option 2"
OptionList(3) = "Option 3"
```

to pull from a range like this

```
Dim OptionList() as Variant
OptionList = Range("A1:A3")
```

In your "button_onclick()" procedure stored in a module add this code:

```
'This is set by the code in UserForm1
Public SelectedOption As String

Sub Button1_OnClick()
    UserForm1.Show
    MsgBox SelectedOption
End Sub
```

Which gets you this result:

[image]

And when you click submit a message box will pop up showing you which option was selected

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your complete code. But I have a button on my excel sheet. So on clicking that button I need to invoke UserForm_Inititialize(). So how I can do that. The button_onclick code is present in the module1. Now how I can call this method from button_onclick() method. Please let me know regarding this.

Comment: Inside your button_onclick() method run `UserForm1.Show`

Comment: Hi thank you very much it worked. I put the UserForm1.show inside the button_click() method. Now the window displayed with the radio button. Thank you very very much. But the next thing is when I click on button it is not displaying which radio button is clicked. I mean to say the control is not going to commandButton1_onclick() method. My program is like this button_onclick() have the code that was present in UserForm_initializer() and after this function I created one more function called CommandButton1_onclick() which have the code you suggested for command button.

Comment: Change the code in COmmandBUtton1_Clicked to the updated code. I demonstrated how you can get the value of what was selected. The answer has been updated to show how this works with the code you have in a module

Answer (score 1):

Remember in using option buttons, your option buttons need to share the same GroupName.
Your control **Name** is only there for you to refer it back for changing/reading.
Your **Caption** is a string that appear on your userform to the users. 
Your **GroupName** is a string that allows Excel to recognize the option buttons are linked together.

So, if opt1's GroupName is "1" while opt2's GroupName is "2", then you will be able to select both since they are in different Groups.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim opt1 As Control, opt2 As Control

    Set opt1 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", , True)
    With opt1
        .Name = "radioFoo"
        .GroupName = "1"
        .Caption = "Option 1"
    End With

    Set opt2 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", , True)
    With opt2
        .Name = "radioFoo2"
        .GroupName = "1"
        .Caption = "Option 2"
        .Left = 100
    End With

End Sub
```

***EDIT:***
From seeing your edited post and your comment...
No, you don't need to have UserForm_Initialize() method.

It is an Excel-VBA functionality called **Event**.
What it's used for is specifying the userform to do something when userform is initialized (first started).

Similarly from your code, Button1_Click() is an event as well.
Since you are telling Excel to do the following at the event where Button1 is clicked by the user...

Anyways, let me briefly explain to you what option buttons do.
A **group** of option buttons forces the user to select only one option out of options given by the program.
And an option button in VBA only allows you to create one option. So, if you want to create 2 options, you must create 2 option buttons.
But there is just one problem: what if you want to create 2 groups of option buttons so that the user can select 2 separate options? For example, food and drinks?
VBA presents us a property of an option button called **GroupName**. GroupName allows VBA to distinguish between separate groups of option buttons.
Therefore, in every option button you create, it is essential that you initialize its GroupName value. If you see any implementation of option button without GroupName, you are playing with fire.

So, let's finally take a look at your code:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ' Some operatin is done here to get the list of values in lResult

    Dim rad1 As Control, rad2 As Control
    Set rad1 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "radioFoo1", True)
    rad1.Caption = "bar"
    rad1.Left = 10
    rad1.Width = 10
    rad1.Top = 10
    rad1.GroupName = "Group1"

    Set rad2 = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.OptionButton.1", "radioFoo2", True)
    rad2.Caption = "foo"
    rad2.Left = 10
    rad2.Width = 10
    rad2.Top = 50
    rad2.GroupName = "Group1"
End Sub
```

Just one thing:
- As I've implicitly mentioned before, an option button with only one option does not mean anything. If you are looking for on/off kind of functionality, you might as well go with checkbox.
  So, I've created another option button defining it to be in the same group as the first option button you've created (rad1).

Hope it helps.

Cheers,
kpark

Be sure to select the best answer when the question/problem has been answered/solved.
Thanks.

Comment: thank you very much for your solution. I will try this out. I did not created userform_initilize() method. Do I need to create it. I have edited my post by adding the code that I am working on, if possible could you please check my code once and let me know where I can put userform_initialize() method. I am very sorry since I am new to this field I am finding little difficulty to understand how the userform works.

Comment: Userform_Initialize() can be found by right clicking on the userform module and clicking on view code. Then above the code window, you will see two dropdown menus. On the first menu, select Userform and in the second menu, select Initialize and editor should do the rest for you.

Comment: Thank you very much kpark91. I really appreciate your help and information helped me to understand the concepts. Yes, I edited my code as per your suggestion and ran the code. I got an error message **"User-defined type not defined"** and hence I changed the type of the rad1 and rad2 from **Control** to **Variant** type now its not showing an error message but it is also not showing any form or button. If possible could you please help me regarding this.